# Google SignIn not working when opt Add account option

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am trying to implement **Google Sign-In into my android application**. Although i have implemented it successfully.

But the problem is when i am try to login via existing email it is working fine. But when try to add new Account via Button **Add account** (see in the screenshot) its not giving result.

[image]

> My screen goes blur nothing happening for long time and when i click
>   on the Screen its given 0(`RESULT_CANCELED`).

[image]

**My code is :**

**`onCreate()`**

```
private SignInButton signInButton; 
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient; 
private static final int SIGN_IN_REQ_CODE = 100; 


   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
     signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override 
       public void onClick(View v) { 
                                  signIn(); 
                                   }
       });
       googleIntegration()
    }


private void googleIntegration() { 
     GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN) .requestEmail() .build(); 
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).build(); 

}

private void signIn() { 
  Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient); 
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_REQ_CODE); 
}

  @Override 
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
       if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQ_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {                       GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data); 
              if (result.isSuccess()) { 
               Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } 
            }else { 
              Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to sign in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            } 
    }
```

So in the failure case i am getting **"Failed to sign in"** Toast.

Or is there any other step i have to do to deal with this issue??

Comment: *So is it work like that or its a bug?* without code in the question itself I can only say: **sorry, it's androidhive - source of the bad tutorials**

Comment: @Selvin check now

Comment: @AjeetChoudhary how to resolve this issue ?
if you resolved this answer, please share your answer Thank You!

Comment: @HardikVasani i have tried few solutions but nothing worked for me, As per shared link by parekhkruti26 this issue is in google-services SDK. There is still no solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is reported by many peers long back, around almost a month ago. You can see yourself about the issue reported in this [github link](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/358).

> Hey all,
>
> Thank you for reporting this issue. We are aware of it and taking it
>   seriously. A fix for this issue will come over-the-air through an
>   update to Google Play services, there's not much you can do to
>   mitigate this right now besides just wait.

Quoted by a personnel over github

Last 3 days ago, they have said that this issue is not yet fixed.